How to use OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection Policy in mule4
I have to apply OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection Policy in mule4 application but not sure how to implement this. I can find below documentation for the same but not sure exactly apply this to code.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/gateway/latest/policies-included-oauth-token-introspection
Please let me know how i can apply this policy or if there will be any portal or page for the same implementation.

The question is not clear. What are you trying to do? Are you familiar with API Manager and applying policies?

@aled OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection Policy is not in the api manager policy. please refer https://docs.mulesoft.com/gateway/latest/policies-included-oauth-token-introspection

You question is tagged for Mule but the documentation link you shared is for Flex Gateway. Please clarify your question.

@aled yes this is to implement flex gateway in mule

Flex Gateway and Mule are two different and incompatible products. Please clarify.
